# assign variable if condition match in for loop

Tags: php, if-statement, for-loop, yii2

Suppose I have an array with ie. $user_all_activity in code, i must check 5 activity in 10 minute(which is done by getDifference(),which return true is condition matches).If condition matched the condition,now i must check 5 activity in 10 minute after the condition matched.And this will be repeated several times.I put some late night programming here.

```
//$$user_all_activity take all activity of user A
if(!$user_all_activity == NULL)
{
    $size = sizeof($user_all_activity);
    //$prev_array = array();
    for( $i=0; $i<$size-1;$i++)
    {
        if($i>3)
        {
                $prev_array = $user_all_activity[$i-4];
                $current_array = $user_all_activity[$i];
                //get difference check for difference 10
                if($this->getDifference($current_array,$prev_array))
                {
                        echo "Table update at id ".$current_array['id']."      </br>";

                }


         }
    }
 }
```

The problem for me when condition matched.I must check again the same thing.May be good to use recursive.Sorry for not explaining the problem before.Hope you get the question.Thanks

Comment: very low quality question. please define the space of ur question clearly. what do you have and what is the desired result? It better you put an example

Comment: @Trix please check update in question.Hope you will understand.

Comment: Are you asking for a way to remove `if($i>3)`?

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable, and then check it later.

```
if($user_all_activity != NULL)
{
    $size = sizeof($user_all_activity);
    $difference_found = false;
    for( $i=0; $i<$size-1;$i++)
    {
        if($i>3)
        {
            $prev_array = $user_all_activity[$i-4];
            $current_array = $user_all_activity[$i];
            //get difference check for difference 10
            if($this->getDifference($current_array,$prev_array))
            {
                echo "Table update at id ".$current_array['id']."      </br>";
                $difference_found = true;

            }
            if ($difference_found) {
                // do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I really don't understand the question. Where are minutes in this?